# Create native application does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, native

I've tried to convert my Windows forms application and finally got a file in the cache that is called `MyApp.ni.exe`. 

When I try to start this file I get a message box:

> That this is not a valid Win32-application.

Can anyone tell me what to do with this file or how to get a native standalone app? 


I've heard that `.NET Native` cannot be used for this?

Comment: `ngen` != `.NET Native`

Comment: What do you mean by native? Do you want to remove the CLR/framerk dependency completely? - That's what .Net Native does

Comment: *"tried to convert my Windows forms application"* - can you tell more about this step?

Comment: Hi Alex, this is exactly what I'm going to do. Unfortunately I cannot select the .NET native-option in my Visual Studio 2015 Build settings.